# Update the database and delete the old one

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

If you have updated the application with SQLite database inside, and add a table that does not appear until you delete the application data and cache, I want it to do this automatically

Comment: My database is read only, not write

Comment: I found some solutions, but when I change the database and run the application through the emulator, it does not delete the old database

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more Information on your topic so that we can help you more efficiently.

First: If you want to uninstall and install the app programatically, you can do this by getting the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

permission and then asking the user to uninstall your app. After that you can programatially install a new app with `PackageManager`. This only makes sense if you do not delete the app where you control any downloads with.

Second:
You can update an SQLiteDb without uninstalling the app. There is a SQL-Funciton called `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and `CREATE TABLE` where you can infuence your DB while the app is running. if it needs a Restart you could use the `processPhoenix` lib.